# How can I get Eclipse to launch Ant in one keypress?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, ant, keyboard-shortcuts

I changed the keybinding for `Run Ant Build` to <kbd>F10</kbd> when `Editing Javascript Source` and also tried `In Windows`. In both cases F10 opens the file menu.

If I press <kbd>F11</kbd> while the ant build.xml is highlighted, it runs. If I press <kbd>F11</kbd> any other time Eclipse opens up the Debug Configuration dialog. If I try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F11</kbd> it tells me there are no launch configurations.

I basically have an Ant build that concats and minifies all the js files in my project. I would like for it to run in lieu of compile while I am editing that project and to be ignored otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you add a builder to the project and make the step to process the .js files part of the build action? Go to the project properties an choose builders. Click 'New...', choose the Ant Builder and configure it.

This way Eclipse will invoke the Ant script when building the project and you don't need to perform that step manually.